# Прошу объяснить, как работать с YQL

Tags: ajax, фреймворк

Yahoo разработали фреймворк, позволяющий обращаться к страницам и получать с них данные.
Меня интересует получение содержимого элементов с определенным css селектором.

Однако все мои попытки сделать что-то вроде

```
select * from data.html.cssselect where url='http://yahoo.com' AND css='.js-stream-content'
```

Выдают null как результат